# How to get the password for the database created in webmatrix

Tags: mysql, database, webmatrix

I am trying to create a database in Webmatrix. When I go to the 'Databases' pane, there is already one database created in the name 'simplecms207'. What database is this?

And when I right click and click on 'New MySql Database', the user id is root and the password is in asterisks. I am not able to change this password. I need the password to connect to the database from PHP.

When I right click on the database and say 'Copy Connection String', it only gives me a series of asterisks for the password. Below, It says 'Connection String is in a web.config file'.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't want to use the root password for your PHP app.
2. Go to the file pane, and open web.config where you will find a connection string with the password.